# VisualStudio2015にてパフォーマンスプロファイラーが正常に実行されない不具合

Tags: visual-studio

VisualStudio2015のパフォーマンスプロファイラーを使用しています。
CPU使用率をプロファイルしたいです。

PC起動後、初回のプロファイルは成功するのですが、
2回目以降のプロファイル結果が、「プロファイル対象のアプリ名.exe(PID:###)」しか表示されません。
exeの横に折り畳み制御の三角ボタンも出てきません。詳細な関数名の表示が出来ず困っています。

初回のプロファイル時のみ
「このアプリがデバイスに変更を加えることを許可しますか？
　VSStandardCollector.exe」
の警告が表示され、
「はい」を選択するとプロファイルに成功するので
VSStandardCollector.exeが2回目以降正常に起動できていない感じではあるのですが…。

同じような現象になったことある方いらっしゃるでしょうか。
解決方法を教えていただきたいです。

ちなみにVisualStudio2019では問題なくプロファイル出来ています。

Comment: 例えば両方のVisualStudioがインストールされているのが同一PCなのか別PCなのか、それぞれのVisualStudioの起動時に管理者権限を指定して起動しているか否か、環境変数`PATH`の設定内容・記述順番がそれぞれのVisualStudioの動作時に相応しいものになっているか、といったことを調べたり追記してみてください。なお状況の説明やエラーメッセージ等は端折ったりせず、表示されたままを画像ではなくテキストで提示してください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)